# hyperlinks not clickable in email

Tags: php, forms, hyperlink, render

I have a PHP email-form that works fine except it isn't rendering certain hyperlinks correctly.
Here's what happens:

The form is on `form.php` and gets sent to `action.php` using `$_POST`.
`action.php` contains all the php email processing logic such as posted fields, header info, and `@mail`, etc, etc.

**form.php**
Links are pulled from a database and echoed out in a `textarea` in table form.
This works fine.

These are then sent to `action.php`, which also works, ie, this page is receiving the info fine.

**This is what's wrong**  (*one link works, one link does not*)
If link `<a href="http://www.mysite.com">Link #1</a>` is echoed out on `action.php` it will render properly in the email.
However, if that same link `<a href="http://www.mysite.com">Link #1</a>` is echoed out on page `form.php` inside the `textarea` that gets posted, it will lose it's `href` inside of the email.

Why isn't the link echoed out on the form page rendering properly, when the same link will render if echoed from `action.php`?

Keep in mind the form is functioning fine and that the hyperlink will render properly if echoed out on page `action.php`, but not `form.php`.

Thanks for input.

** ** ** Releative Code ** ** **

**action.php**:

`<textarea id="box_5" name="box_5" cols="45" rows="10" ><a href="http://www.mysite.com">Link #1</a></textarea>`

this gets sent to form.php. the `<a>...</a>` is generated by a mysql query:

**form.php** here is what happens to the posted element:

`$list = $_POST['box_5'];
 $email_message .= '<u>Items  </u><br><table cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:10px;min-width:390px;border:1px solid #cccccc;">' .clean_string($list). '</table>';

  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, $add);`

when it's viewed in email client it loses the `href` and is only "Link #1".

Comment: If I understand correctly... are you trying to render an anchor tag inside a textarea?

Comment: @Malcoda yes, then that is posted to `action.php` where it gets sent inside the email message

Comment: Without seeing the code, I could only guess that, if your problem is losing the href attribute, you may want to check your escaping and quotation marks. Html won't render inside a textarea, but it shouldn't strip an href, since it's just treated as text.

Comment: Code has been added, but I don't think that's where the problem is.